# Schengen visa information for Sweden

Tags: visas, schengen, france, sweden

I want to get a visa from the Swedish embassy to visit Sweden. May I visit France using the same visa?

Comment: Is there any reason you'd think that you wouldn't be able to visit France with that visa?

Comment: There are multiple questions regarding ability to visit other Schengen countries on the forum.

Comment: One one trip? Multiple trips?